# How to show winform chart Axis X in grouped category?

Tags: vb.net, charts, visualization

I'm a newbie to Vb.net. I'm in progress to create a dashboard from sale data using VB.net chart. I bind data to chart from a datatable. In this datatable, I have a column named "YearMonth". This column is the value for Axis X.

Things work well, but I want the Axis X to group months for each year, so that the Axis X will not be too long for the chart.

Sorry if what I said was not clear. Below is what I've done:
[image]

Here is what I want:
[image]

Is there anyway to achieve this in VB.net?